# String matcher regex

Tags: regex

I am writing a compiler for a simple program language. In this language string variables can be defined as follows:

```
String str = "hello";
```

The definition of a valid string is simplified, no escaped characters are allowed (so `"\"hello\""` is not a valid string because it has too many quotation marks, and `"\n\n"` is legal as a 4 character string it isn't two new lines). I am trying to write a regex to match the string literal part. The simplest thing to do is `".*"`. This works pretty well but has a problem that it also matches

```
"hello" safdfasasf"
```

This is an illegal string because strings can't have internal quotation marks. I tried several alternatives that didn't work, for example: `"(?!")"` which matches anything that is not a quotation mark and then expects a quotation mark, but that doesn't work because it doesn't recognize the last quote either. What is the correct regex for this?

Comment: `I am writing a compiler for a simple program language. ... What is the correct regex for this?` If you are writing a compile for a programming language, where is the grammar? Use that to write a regex.

Comment: It's not that well defined, its a homework exercise where the professors defined the language. How would I formally declare the grammar?

Comment: It looks like you're on the wrong track. Usually regular expressions is not the best tool for lexical analysis. Also writing your own lexer based on finite automata can be tricky, and if it's not the key point of your homework -  probably it's better to use existed ones (ANTLR, Flex and so on).

Comment: For all the downvoters, can you please comment on why you are downvoting. This is my first question on regexes so I would like to know what is off-topic about it. Does it not show enough work or is it missing a MCVE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you're looking for something like

```
"[^"]*"
```

Comment: OK. When you said you tried several alternatives, I was afraid this would be too easy! Glad it worked. By the way, can string literals contain newlines in the language?

Comment: No. It is pretty simplified so that it would be easy for us students.

Comment: I guess I didn't know the difference between ?! and ^.